# How can I know when a bluetooth device isn't connected anymore?

Tags: ios, swift, singleton, core-bluetooth

I have a page where I can search for the available devices (a table view displays the advertising ones) and connect to it. On that page in particular, I've used the core bluetooth functions and once connected I pass a reference of the connected peripheral to a singleton class I use to perform any bluetooth commands from any page. Everything is working fine, with the exception of when a device disconnects. In the singleton object class I had made, I've put in code within the didDisconnect peripheral function to keep a reference of which device is disconnecting and to rescan for available peripherals. If I find one which has disconnected, I reconnect within the didDiscoverPeripheral function. I've also defined 7 different connection states which I store as a flag in NSUserDefaults. '6' and '7' are for when two devices are connected and one of them disconnects.
Also whenever I use a custom function to send a command I perform a check to see whether the peripheral exists within the reference array. If not I dont send a command.

Here is a snippet of the didDisconnectPeripheral function:

```
// If disconnected, start searching again
    func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: NSError?) {

        print("Disconnected")
        if peripheral == self.easeDevice {

            modeData.setObject(6, forKey: "ConnectionState")
            modeData.synchronize()
            connectedPeripheralArray.removeAtIndex(0)
            central.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)

        } else if peripheral == self.easeDevice2 {

            modeData.setObject(7, forKey: "ConnectionState")
            modeData.synchronize()
            connectedPeripheralArray.removeAtIndex(1)
            central.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)

        }

    }
```

All the above I had made in the singleton object class. The issue I'm facing is that when a device does disconnect on any particular page, it doesn't go to the didDisconnectPeripheral in the singleton. (Since the singleton contains all the bluetooth code, I haven't imported the CoreBluetooth Module and functions on every ViewController class. Instead I just call what i need). If I had defined the coreBluetooth functions on every page, I could probably get to know when a device disconnects. So currently, when I try to write a command, the app crashes as the device isn't available to be written to. Has anyone found a way to constantly monitor disconnection of devices? Or a more streamlined simple way of managing ble connections within a singleton? Any relevant insight is welcome

Comment: You will get a call to the delegate method you have shown. Your singleton should guard against attempting to communicate with a disconnected peripheral and return some sort of error state to the view controller that made the request. There is no reason for your app to crash if you have coded correctly. By the way, you can just call `connect` straight away on the disconnected peripheral and iOS will reconnect once it is in range again. No need to scan for the peripheral again.

Comment: yeah, I guess it makes sense to connect straight away from the function. I'll do that. Well, I haven't really defined a delegate for the above method. The only thing I'm confused about is the flow of things. As in once I pass a peripheral reference to the singleton class, will the peripheralDisconnect function in the singleton be called automatically when a disconnect happens? If so, then I think i can define a protocol and a delegate to notify the current page of the disconnection.

Comment: The delegate method will be called on which ever object is set as the delegate. This should be your singleton.

Comment: hmm yeah that makes sense. I figure its about time i define a protocol. Thanks!

Comment: @Paulw11 Hey I implemented a protocol and a delegate for the singleton class to pass the disconnected peripheral wherever the protocol is conformed to. The issue is that the disconnect function is never in the singleton even when the device gets disconnected. Can you have a look at this question and offer some insight! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37789690/diddisconnectperipheral-function-is-not-being-called