# didDisconnectPeripheral function is not being called

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-bluetooth

I'm going to break down what the flow for connection is for the first time a user wants to connect to a BLE Peripheral Device. I think I may be doing something that upsets the natural flow of the CoreBluetooth Module. My app currently works with regards to connecting and sending commands to a BLE device.

To connect, I first land on a page with a tableview which displays the devices available to connect to.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //self.centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: blueCoreDelegate, queue: nil)
        self.centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)

        // setting the central manager in BlueCoreManager as the same
        BlueCoreManager.shared.getCentralManager(centralManager!)

    }
```

BlueCoreManager is a singleton that I have created to easily manage multiple connections. At this point the centralManagerDidUpdateState function is called.
I know that it goes to the centralManagerDidUpdateState function in both the current page and the singleton. In both I scan for peripherals.

In the current page: I append the discovered peripherals onto the tableview.

In the singleton: I keep track the connection states

Now once a cell is tapped on the current page, I connect to it:

```
// Connect to peripheral on tap
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let peripheral = peripherals[indexPath.row]

        if peripheral.name != nil {

            self.centralManager!.connectPeripheral(peripheral, options: nil)
            print("Connecting to \(peripheral.name!)")

        }

    }
```

After the above, the didConnectPeripheral on the currentPage is called, where I update connectionStates and call the syncPeripheral function in the singleton.

```
func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didConnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral) {

        // setting connection state to 4 (currently connected)
        let cstate = over.valueForKey("ConnectionState") as! Int

        if cstate == 4 {

            print("ConnectionState: One Connected. Connecting to Second")
            over.setObject(5, forKey: "ConnectionState")
            over.synchronize()
            print("Connected To Two")
        } 
.......

.......

         else if cstate == 7 {

            print("ConnectionState: Disconnected from secondary. Connecting to Second")
            over.setObject(5, forKey: "ConnectionState")
            over.synchronize()
            print("Connected To Two")

        }

        // synchronizing the current peripheral in BlueCoreManager
        BlueCoreManager.shared.syncPeripheral(peripheral)

        displayAlert("Connected!", message: "You are connected to \(peripheral.name!)")


    }
```

This is the syncPeripheral function which is then called, where I set the peripherals' delegates and call discoverServices whichever one is connected.

```
func syncPeripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        let cstate = modeData.valueForKey("ConnectionState")

        switch(cstate as! Int) {
        case 0: print("Connection State Powered On")
                print("Not keeping any reference")

        case 4: print("Connection State To One")
                self.easeDevice = peripheral
                print(peripheral.name!)
                self.easeDevice!.delegate = self
                self.connectedPeripheralArray.insert(peripheral, atIndex: 0)
                self.familiarPeripherals.insert(peripheral, atIndex: 0)
                print(connectedPeripheralArray[0].name)
            self.easeDevice!.discoverServices(nil)

        case 5: print("Connection State To Two")
                self.phy = peripheral
                print(peripheral.name!)
                self.phy!.delegate = self
                self.connectedPeripheralArray.insert(peripheral, atIndex: 1)
                self.familiarPeripherals.insert(peripheral, atIndex: 1)
            self.phy!.discoverServices(nil)
        case 6: print("Connection State Disconnected from One")
        case 7: print("Connection State Disconnected from device two")
        default: print("Connection State = \(cstate)")
        }

    }
```

I then discover the services and characteristics in the singleton NSObject class. In the disconnect function, I'm updating the disconnect states and trying to reconnect to the disconnected peripheral. Also I'm passing the disconnected peripheral through a protocol I defined.

```
// If disconnected, connect again
func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: NSError?) {

// Delegate which passes disconnected peripherals
if delegate != nil {

    delegate!.peripheralDidDisconnect("\(peripheral.name!)")

}

print("Disconnected")
if peripheral == self.easeDevice {

    modeData.setObject(6, forKey: "ConnectionState")
    modeData.synchronize()
    connectedPeripheralArray.removeAtIndex(0)
    self.centralManager!.connectPeripheral(peripheral, options: nil)

} else if peripheral == self.phy {

    modeData.setObject(7, forKey: "ConnectionState")
    modeData.synchronize()
    connectedPeripheralArray.removeAtIndex(1)
    self.centralManager!.connectPeripheral(peripheral, options: nil)

}

}
```

The only problem is that the above function never gets called on the singleton object (The singleton is an NSObject class, could this be the reason why?). What am I missing?! This issue is driving me insane! Any insights are highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, is the `didDisconnectPeripheral` function not called, or is it called, but not the function your singleton define ?

Comment: The disconnect function is not being called in the singleton. After I connect on the table page, I pass a reference of the peripheral to the singleton object and move on to the next page. I haven't defined the didDisconnectPeripheral on the table page since I will be navigating away from it.

Comment: I  think your `CBCentralManager` is not operating anymore, otherwise the function would be called for sure. Maybe you can check that when you "navigate away" from your TableView, your `CBCentralManager` that is stored in your Singleton (if I am right) is still able to operate. See [the CBCentralManagerState documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManager_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CBCentralManagerState)

Comment: I suspect the same. I'm just trying to reconnect from syncPeripheral in the singleton class to see if it'll work then.

Comment: Nope, it didn't work. And yeah I am storing the centralManager in the singleton but I'm not sure whats going on.

Comment: The thing is, when you expect `didDisconnectPeripheral` to be called, the instance of your initial `CBCentralManager` is not present anymore. You expect the function to be called by the instance in your singleton. If it is not called, it means that the instance of `CBCentralManager` in your singleton is not monitoring anything. I'm not familiar with passing references in Swift, but I think the way you pass the `centralManger` to your singleton may not be good.

Comment: I know that the centralManager keeps track. But somewhere in the code, I'm losing it. I'm still trying to figure out where it's happening

Comment: Why are you allocating a CBCentralManager in your view controller and in your singleton?  You should only have one, in your singleton. Your singleton should be the delegate and it should notify the rest of your app via NSNotification when events occur. The fact that you are getting delegate methods called in two places indicates that you have two CBCentralManagers, so it seems likely that the one with the connection has no delegate when the disconnect occurs